# MsBuild with solution files with DefineConstants

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

Currently, in my automated build, I use the devenv.exe to build my solution files:

```
devenv /build myproject1.sln
```

Now, I want to create two versions of my application, the normal version, and the light version. The source code for these two versions are the same, it's just that in light version some of the features are disabled, and for this I use [#define lite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx) preprocessor directives ( In csproject file, these constants are defined under `DefineConstants` Property Group).

In MsBuild--or just normal devenv build--is it possible to specify whether the symbol I want should be present in the build? The reason I ask this is because I want to build my `sln` file first time with the `lite` preprocessor directives ( for lite version), and the second time, without the `lite` preprocessor directives ( for full version).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your project file add new **PropertyGroup** section for lite version

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(LiteVersion)'=='true'">
   <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);lite</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Remove **lite** from all definitions of **DefineConstants**.

```
MSBuild.exe  myprojeect1.sln
MSBuild.exe  myprojeect1.sln /p:LiteVersion=true
```

You can create additional configuration in VS to switch between versions. But it can lead to configuration mismatches when you forgot to add a flag to lite config. I can suggest more elegant solution. Create .bat file or change the link to run myproject1.sln:

```
set LiteVersion=true
devenv.exe myproject1.sln
```

Comment: Probably best to put the custom group above below the normal ones that define debug, release, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Create two configurations in your sln file - one for the Lite and one for the Normal. In the Lite config, define the preprocessor directive via the Project Properties dialog.

Then, when doing the build using devenv.com, specify the correct configuration in which to build.

Comment: would you like to present an example on how to do this?

Comment: This is fine for 1 property which changes configuration, but doesn't scale well.. What if you have 2+ configurations? Maybe a special logging build. You would then need 2 * 2 * 2 configs e.g. Debug_Lite_Logging - all gets very messy... I prefer sergio's answer.